# How should I represent a latitude and longitude in Postgres without using PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql

How should I represent a latitude and longitude in Postgres without using PostGIS? The system I am using does not allow SQL passthrough so I cannot use POSTGIS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the builtin POINT datatype without postgis.

Answer (score 6):

You could also either use separate columns for `latitude` and `longitude` or [create your own type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html). Either way it may be good to [constrain](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html) the allowed values, in this example I also use [domains](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html) to avoid repeating constraints if the type is used in more than one table:

```
create domain latitude_t as double precision not null 
                                             check(value>=-90 and value<=90);
create domain longitude_t as double precision not null 
                                              check(value>-180 and value<=180);

create type geocoord_t as (latitude latitude_t, longitude longitude_t);

create table my_table(id serial, geocoord geocoord_t);

insert into my_table(geocoord) values ((31.778175,35.22995));

select id, (geocoord).* from my_table;
 id | latitude  | longitude
----+-----------+-----------
  1 | 31.778175 |  35.22995
```

Answer (score 5):

For non GIS application I just use columns, as suggested by Jack, though I don't bother with with the check value. It is a good idea to also specify the datum (IE [NAD27](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Datum)) in an additional column, as the datum is important for proper interpretation of the values.